# Как изучать cocos2dx?

Tags: графика, разработка-игр, android, cocos2d

Начал изучение библиотеки. Вроде бы все более менее получилось по первым гайдам, но вот в чем проблема. Я просто не понимаю как на ней создавать игры, то есть, не могу пока сообразить где что и как использовать. Знаний у меня кроме как по С++ нету, раньше игры не делал. В документации нету полноценного описания как и что, а только описание API. Может быть проблема в том что нету опыта совсем? Может быть нужно было сначала серьезно поизучать графику, opengl, а потом только браться за эту библиотеку? Что посоветуете?

Comment: Мне кажется у вас не совсем верная формулировка:

> 'Я просто не понимаю как **на ней** создавать игры'

> 'раньше игры не делал' 

Могу ошибаться, но проблема тут не в cocos2dx

Comment: Формулировка верная с точки зрения того, что изучение этой библиотеки конечная цель. Проблема в том, что я многое просто пропустил и не знаю как наверстать. Что изучать?

Comment: > "В документации нету полноценного описания как и что, а только описание API"

А вы только по туториалам код умеете писать? :)

Comment: Ищи примеры в опенСорсе игр на этом кокосе, смотри как делают другие, найти кокосовские форумы и пробуй наверстывать, молодой падаван

Comment: У меня вопрос: при чем тут android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Берете примеры туториалов в инете под Cocos2d-iphone, читаете доку под него же, открываете код и используете те же классы, но только в 2dx. По идеи, там полное сходство вплоть до названия.

**UPD**
Если капнуть чуть глубже(из моей памяти), то:

- в кокосе основные понятия - это сцена, слои и текстуры. Обычно одна сцена - это один экран(в нашем случае активити). На сцену добавляются слои. На слои добавляются текстуры или что-то еще. Текстура по суте - это картинка.
- для текста используются CCLabel и его производные. В текст можно подгружать свои шрифты из assets например
- переход между окнами(сценами, слоями) реализуется через паттерн синглтон, как правило, и просто один слой выкидываем - вставляем другой, передавая между ними параметры какой слой текущий.
- у нас есть одно активити в котором есть просто GLSurfaceView, но только кокосовый, внутри него происходит вся канитель.
- работа с анимацией, музыкой реализована поверх андроидовых(ну или другой нативной ос) апи, но все нужные обертки есть. На счет анимации - есть много классов аля CCMoveTO с разной функцией(кривой) в основе. Гугл поможет капнуть глубже.
- обновление UI происходит обычно к 1/60 и когда dalvik запускает поток сборщика мусора вся логика игры может покорябиться из-за задержек, поэтому нужно еще помнить об этой особенности.
- в слое(по-моему) есть метод update(), который как раз и работает по тику 1 к 60, обновляя UI. Этот метод обычно реализовывают по-своему, запихивая например логику движения какого-либо персонажа или что-то подобное.

Все это актуально для Cocos2d-android-1 - порта кокоса под дроид с кучей багов.
Если что-то вспомню еще - добавлю сюда.

Answer (score 1):

кокс - инструмент, прикольный, но инструмент. Понять как строить дом, и дом построишь так и тут. Есть классная книга "Объектно-ориентированный анализ и проектирование" Бретт Маклафлин, поймете как спроектировать приложение-поймете как спроектировать игру. Можно хоть 50 языков знать, но если не можешь адекватно декомпозировать задачу и спроектировать - игру не победишь, запутаешься в кассах, методах и т.п.